# SWFUpload drag and drop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dropbox, swfupload

I'm currently implementing swfupload in a project I'm working on, I initially started using the new HTML5 File Apis but decided to change to swfupload given that the Dropbox web app uses swfupload to perform uploads directly from the website.

The Dropbox web app supports drag & drop using swfupload, does someone knows how Dropbox accomplished this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would implement two code paths

- one for XMLHttpRequest2 supporting Browsers using its file api (with easy to implement DnD support)
- a fallback if XMLHttpRequest2 is not available (IE) that uses swfupload

I don't know if Dropbox supports DnD upload in IE, but my guess would be no.